# The element in your flow has validation errors - posting to chatter with text template

Tags: visual-workflow, chatter, action

I'm trying to post to chatter via flow mentioning a user. However it is returning the error: `The element in your flow has validation errors`

I have the following in my text template:

`@[{$User.Id}] This is a test.`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check all the variables that are created in the flow.
Even if this variable is not used in this process because it is present it might cause an issue.